# Content not visible in Mac Safari

Tags: macos, safari

I am working on a project where the content is not appearing in Macintosh machines. I checked in two mac machine with Safari, it's appearing nowhere, and in one of them it worked with FF and not in another.

How would you guys proceed in such a situation ?

The site can be seen at: http://mfp.kigoobe.fr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone from a different forum replied to this and I thought to share the solution. The problem was I used custom fonts in the site which were not visible in Safari / Mac.